# python ProjectEuler task 4 Using while loop

Tags: python

i wanted to do the project euler problems by using python.
but i am having problems with the following task:

A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 x 99.
Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

my code for the given task:

```
def palindrome_number():
  n=0 
  lower_range = 100
  upper_range = 999
  while x >= lower_range or x <= upper_range and y >= lower_range or y <= upper_range:
    z = x * y
    while z > n:
      s = str(x * y)
      if s == s[::-1]:
        n = x * y
  print(n)
```

now i dont know how to check for all the x and y numbers varying from 100-999.
i thought it has to be like in my code, but it doesnt work

Comment: what are x and y initialized as?

Comment: x has to be bigger than lower range and smaller than upper range, i want to iterate from 100 to 999

Comment: why do you have a while, why not just an if, and instead of calculating x*y repeatedly use z. you haven't initialized x or y and no where are they incremented

Comment: Just as a tip, "it doesnt work" generally isn't useful.  Try to include specific errors, what the expected behavior is vs. what you're seeing, etc.

Comment: ok thanks, i will remind this for future questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1: using  a generator expression

Actually the problem can be solved in one line :)

```
max(x*y for x in range(100, 1000) for y in range(100, 1000) if str(x*y)==str(x*y)[::-1])
```

---

### Solution 2: using a `for` loop

`for` loops are better suited for this kind of operation than `while` loops. Below is the solution (I have only replaced your while with two `for` loops. The first loop tells the variable `x` to run from 100 to 999 and the second one tells `y` to do the same. With these two loops you will try out all combinations for `x` and `y`.)

```
def palindrome_number():
    n = 0
    lower_range = 100
    upper_range = 999
    for x in range(lower_range, upper_range+1):
        for y in range(lower_range, upper_range+1):
            z = x * y
            if z > n:  # an *if* suffices ;)
              s = str(x * y)
              if s == s[::-1]:
                n = x * y
    print(n)
```

---

### Solution 3: using a `while` loop

To get the same thing with `while` loops you would have to take care of changing `x` and `y` to get all combinations:

```
x = y = lower_range
while x >= lower_range and x <= upper_range:  # (*and* instead of *or*)
    while y >= lower_range and y <= upper_range:  # (again you want the >= *and* the <= to be fulfilled)
        z = x * y
        if z > n:
            s = str(x * y)
            if s == s[::-1]:
                n = x * y
        y += 1  # change y to get all combinations
    y = lower_range
    x += 1  # change x to get all combinations
```

Comment: thx for the solution - but cant i do this also with a while loop? wouldnt i just need to add the incrementation to x and y? and if so - how could i do it

Comment: I added the solution with while. Mind the first line: you have to initialize x and y if you want a while-loop. Also mind the indentation when incrementing x and y.

Comment: thx - i think i am close to understanding while and for loops. but can it be possible that using the while loop will take a huge amount of time to get the solution? because by doing so - the loop just keeps going

Comment: Don't worry, it won't take long ;) The while-loop does the exact same thing as the for loop (only the developer has to do more (x+=1)). It quits after both x and y have reached 999. And computers are so fast nowadays that they will try out all 900^2 x-y-combinations in milliseconds :)

Comment: the for loop is working fine for me. but the while loop is either giving me a 0 as solution (while using repl.it python 3.0) or just doesnt stop running (with visual studios)

Comment: See my update (added y = lower_range) 
I forgot to reset y - another reason to stick to for loops ;)

Comment: i am very thankful. thanks for your explanaitons and help